# How can I have the PowerPoint Slide Sorter on my laptop's screen, and the full-screen slide on the projector?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow, projector

I'll be doing a rather non-linear presentation (more of a Q&A) where I'll need to pull up arbitrary slides from a long presentation. The fastest way I can jump from one slide to another is to use the Slide Sorter (View -> Slide Sorter in PowerPoint 2007).

In single-screen mode (or duplicate display), I can click on a slide in Slide Sorter, then press Shift+F5 to display it full-screen. Fantastic, just what I need.

Now how can I do that when a projector is connected, so that on my laptop's screen I see the Slide Sorter, but the audience only sees the slide I selected, full-screen?

Answer (score 1):

Use the presenter view. Then you can see the full-screen on the projector and the slides overview + notes + current slide on your laptop.

You can find this option in the "Slide Show" tab, then "Set up Slide show". Under "Multiple Monitors" check the box "Show presenter view". Note, that you must connect the secondary monitor/projector to check this option.

Comment: Doesn't Work ... I tried it just now!