# PowerPoint Won't Put Display On Projector Screen

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, external-display

I have a course to present in half an hour.

i'm using PowerPoint (2007, I think)

The screen I want people to see is appearing on my notebook computer.

The screen I want to see on my notebook is appearing on the big screen on the wall.

I found my exact same question [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/544411/how-can-i-have-the-powerpoint-slide-sorter-on-my-laptops-screen-and-the-full-s) on SuperUser, and tried that, but the setting won't take hold. My actual show always appears on my notebook, which is absolutely not what I want.

I have looked for the answer on

- Microsoft's community [HERE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-powerpoint/reversing-swap-display-in-presenter-view/0dca8e76-d19c-4f3a-8552-54067534e0e0)
- Another Site [HERE](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/power-point-presenter-view-outputs-reversed-t930584.html)
- A Google Book [HERE](http://books.google.com/books?id=rGgh4rgSqEcC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=Powerpoint%20displays%20are%20reversed&source=bl&ots=xJR6Vg8yaC&sig=gAbm6EGAi6D2GEq5MlMtTaOJKYc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vmJeU6joH5TYyAHfw4DIDQ&ved=0CHQQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=Powerpoint%20displays%20are%20reversed&f=false) (no help)

They all say the same thing; i.e.,

that I should click on Slide Show > Set Up Show and change "Display slide show on" to your
secondary monitor, i.e. the projector.

I tried that with this setting, like this...

[image] (sorry for the small size)

I click "OK" and PowerPiont seems to accept it, but the setting doesn't hold. I continue to see the screens reversed.

When I click on the same squence again, I see that the setting did not take hold. Here's the screen cap when I clicked on the same sequence a second time...

[image]

What gives ?

What do I do to make the presentation appear on the big screen for my audience to see while my notebook computer has the presenter's screen with the notes and preview and stuff ?

Comment: Which display is marked as Primary in your Display Settings for Windows?

Comment: @techie007 my thinkpad is the primary (i.e., #1)

Comment: Do I fix this by clicking the "Make this my main display" in the windows setting ?

Comment: What OS is your laptop?

Comment: @techie007 I just did that. I think it fixed it. Way to go. Write an answer and I'll check on it.

Comment: @TheCleaner it's Win'7.  Sorry I had to run to the meeting. StackOverFlow wouldn't let me answer you; something about a 15 second waiting period, and resetting some timer; whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you notebook's display is configured as your "Primary" or "Main" display.

This can be checked/adjusted via the Windows Display Properties.

If the notebook display is giving you the choice to make it primary (or the "main display"), then it's not currently the primary, so you should set it as such.

If the correct monitor seems to be primary, but it's still acting this way, then perhaps set the projector display as the Primary, at least until after the presentation. :)

Comment: Actually, it's just the opposite. I make the big screen the primary and the notebook secondary. I think.  I'm off to the meeting now. will get back to you in an hour. You set me thinking in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Unexpected, but hey, as long as it works.  I'll adjust my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:
1. When start displaying and it is not onthe external monitor, try selecting SWAP DISPLAYS two times in a row... surprise.
2. In System Preferences, toggle the [] Displays have separate spaces. Logout and back in before trying PowerPoint again.